Python - How to spread out a set of coordinates so that they're not within 10 miles of each other?
I'm plotting a scatter map with plotly, and I have a lot of markers that are overlapping and very close to each other.
This may be convoluted, but I'm trying to spread them apart by tweaking each coordinates so that they're not within a 10-20 mile radius of each other. Is this possible to do in Python? I would have no idea how to go about doing this.
I am also open to other solutions that I haven't thought of.


Is the number of points important? Could you reduce the number of markers by looping through them, then for each marker, select all other markers within 10-20mile radius, and delete them?

@tomtomnz Yes, the number of points are important. I need all the points to be present on the map.

How many points are there

@Bera About 50/60 points.

Can you add a screenshot showing how the points are scattered?

@Bera Just added a screenshot!

Are you open to clustering the points so that they are visible when you zoom in, but combined together when zoomed out?

If you aren't open to clustering the points, are you open to using leaflet or dash-leaflet instead of plotly to interactively map them?

@jgm_GIS Unfortunately clustering isn't an option and switch to a new mapping library isn't feasible at this point.
